# Unable to print public variable from Views in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

I have declared a public variable in **BaseController** and it's working fine from the controller. But when I'm trying to print this from any view files. This is not working.

[image]

And when I'm declare a public variable in the controller, then this is also not working from view. But working in the controller.

[image]

**What's the problem? And how to solve this?** When the same thing is working in Codeigniter v3.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send your variable in the view like this :

```
$pageTitle = 'Page title';   
$data = array('pageTitle'=> $pageTitle);
$this->load->view('yourview', $data);
```

And then in your view :

```
<?php echo $pageTitle ?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I want to declare some fixed variables which are needed on every page. So I don't want to declare this on every controller. So I decided to declare those in **BaseController**. Because of the previous version of Codeigniter supports that. **core/MY_Controller.php** in CI3

Comment: @ParagDhali Well you could just declare an array like $page_data, create a constructor to load your "page" globals for title etc and fixed. You would only do this in your Front end controllers anyway.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw  I'm also tried this. But not working from view file. this is running only in the controller file. when I **echo $this->** in view then prints the null value. But CI3 works. Don't know whats the problem! Some variables I want to declare in BaseController. Because I don't want to declare every controller.

Comment: @ParagDhali Well CI 4 is a completely different beast, so now you have to stick to the rules. I never knew CI 3 could echo controller properties as I never tried as it wasn't the way to do it even back then. Wait till you try sessions and flashdata :)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I found my answer in another way myself. Sometimes some common variables are needed in every controller. Which is a very nasty method to define those variables in every controller again and again. That is why some common public variable needed. And it's not a harmful thing to make restriction. this is a good feature. If need be, I can tell you how I did it

Comment: @ParagDhali It would be interesting to see what you did.

Comment: @ParagDhali I'm facing the same issue, It seems a lot of people didn't see the Codeigniter 4, I want to declare a global variable in my header which has to pass through every page. In CL3, you load global variable like this: $this->load->vars($data); but in Codeigniter 4 you can't use the same function, so how are you going to do that?

Comment: @ParagDhali how did you achieve it?